# Refresh same livewire component after form wire:submit.prevent

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Please I'd like to refresh same component after form submit. There is an if statement that allows the the form to display in the component. I'd like to refresh the whole component so as not to show the form again after submit.

I already tried emit but I don't think it works for same component.

**Livewire component**

```
 <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Livewire;
    
    use App\Lesson;
    use App\Question;
    use App\QuestionsOption;
    use App\TestsResult;
    use Livewire\Component;
    
    class LessonTest extends Component
    {
    
        public $test_result;
        public $lesson;
        public $test_exists;
        public array $question = [];
    
        //protected $listeners = ['testDone' => 'render'];
    
        public function mount($test_exists, $lesson, $test_result)
        {
            $this->lesson = $lesson;
          
            $this->test_exists = $test_exists;
            $this->test_result = $test_result;
        }
    
        public function lessonTest()
        {
    
            $lesson = Lesson::where('slug', $this->lesson->slug)->firstOrFail();
            $answers = [];
            $test_score = 0;
            foreach ($this->question as $question_id => $answer_id) {
                $question = Question::find($question_id);
                $correct = QuestionsOption::where('question_id', $question_id)
                    ->where('id', $answer_id)
                    ->where('correct', 1)->count() > 0;
                $answers[] = [
                    'question_id' => $question_id,
                    'option_id' => $answer_id,
                    'correct' => $correct,
                ];
                if ($correct) {
                    $test_score += $question->score;
                }
                /*
             * Save the answer
             * Check if it is correct and then add points
             * Save all test result and show the points
             */
            }
            $test_result = TestsResult::create([
                'test_id' => $this->lesson->test->id,
                'user_id' => \Auth::id(),
                'test_result' => $test_score,
            ]);
    
            $test_result->answers()->createMany($answers);
    
            $this->reset(['question']);
          
    
            $this->emit('testDone');
           
    
    
        }
    
      
        public function render()
        {
            return view('livewire.lesson-test');
        }
    }
```

**Livewire Blade View**

```
<div>
    @if ($test_exists)
        <hr />
        <h3>Test: {{ $lesson->test->title }}</h3>
        @if (!is_null($test_result))
            <div class="alert alert-info">Your test score: {{ $test_result->test_result }} /
                {{ $lesson->test->questions->count() }}</div>
        @else
            <form wire:submit.prevent='lessonTest' action="{{ route('lessons.test', [$lesson->slug]) }}"
                method="post">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                @foreach ($lesson->test->questions as $question)
                    <b>{{ $loop->iteration }}. {{ $question->question }}</b>
                    <br />
                    @foreach ($question->options as $option)
                        <input type="radio" wire:model='question.{{ $question->id }}'
                            name="questions[{{ $question->id }}]" value="{{ $option->id }}" />
                        {{ $option->option_text }}<br />
                    @endforeach
                    <br />
                @endforeach
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg refresh" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>

        @endif
        <hr />
    @endif
</div>
```

Comment: When you say `not show`, do you mean clear the form data or hide the form?

Comment: Hide the form and show result updated to the database

Comment: Can you provide the code for your component and blade view.

Comment: Thank You, I got it solved already

Comment: could you post the issue related and the solution for it? this could help some one else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank You. I got it solved, I forget that I passed the test result from the controller before, so I had to recall the test_result and also the test_exist inside the lessonTest action.

```
$this->test_result = TestsResult::where('test_id', $this->lesson->test->id)
        ->where('user_id', \Auth::id())
        ->first();

        $this->test_exists = true;
```